# GoogleMaps SDK IOS - Error Logs switch to using NSSecureUnarchiveFromData

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, sdk

I'm getting this error log using Google Maps SDK from CocoaPods:

> [error] fault: One or more models in this application are using transformable properties with transformer names that are either unset, or set to NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName. Please switch to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer instead. At some point, Core Data will default to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" when nil is specified, and transformable properties containing classes that do not support NSSecureCoding will become unreadable.
>
> CoreData: warning: Property 'value' on Entity 'GMSCacheProperty' is using nil or an insecure NSValueTransformer.  Please switch to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer instead.
>
> Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 3.6.0.0

I have tried Remove StorageWithTileProto.omo from GMSCacheStorage.momd folder, Clean Build Folder and update from GoogleMaps 3.5.0 to 3.6.0 but same issue.

Comment: Did you solve that?

Comment: @tdtkien I removed the CoreData from my Xcode project and defined properties within structures in Swift to store the marker information, as well as made changes to the methods of adding and removing markers on the map. But there were so many changes that I couldn't tell you exactly what was causing the alert.

Comment: I tried many ways but cannot solve it. But my app still work fine